# Number of Users Join At Time Case Scenarios?

Tags: java

I need to know about same action perform at time by different users case scenarios.

For Ex : One room is there.Users continuously joins into room and leaves the room at time.and one more case is no of users try to join same room at time.

How to handle above example cases in java like synchronization or any else.Please suggest me best case to handle this?

I did one sample.Please see the below sample code once :

```
public class Sample{

    private ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
    public synchronized void joinRoom(String name)
    {
        players.add(name);
        //Do something
    }

    public synchronized void leaveRoom(String name)
    {
        for(String uName : players){
            if(uName.equals(name))
            {
                players.remove(uName);//Here is there any possibility to get concurrent modification exception.if gets how to solve
            }
        }

       //Do something
    }
}
```

But i didn't know that cases handle like using above sample code or not.Please suggest me which one is best to handle this cases?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Here's Oracles tutorial on concurrency. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use ConcurrentSkipListSet for this.  It will handle all the synchronization for you and do it  more efficiently.The ConcurrentSkipListSet allows concurrent reads and writes.

Regarding the concurrent modification exception, use an iterator:

```
Iterator<String>  iter = players.iterator();
 while(iter.hasNext()){
   if(iter.next().equals(name)){
    iter.remove();
    break;
  }
}
```